# Python matplotlib MathText with variables

Tags: python, matplotlib

I need to document calculations including

1. the used equation and
2. the variables replaced by the values used

Example: A=1, B=2

C=A+B

3=1+2

I am using Reportlab and create flowable elements with matplotlib. The following code based on the [help](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/text/mathtext.html) and can achieve No.1 from the list above. Two questions arise:

1. How can I insert variable values in my `mathtext_demo`?
2. Is there a way to write the general equation and the one with substituted values and result using some dictionary/solv

   > ```
   > import matplotlib.pylab as plt  
   >
   > mathext_demos = (r'$(\frac{5 - \frac{1}{x}}{4})$')       
   >
   > def make_equation(code,fsize=20,imgheight=70):
   >     fig=plt.figure(figsize=(7, 0.1))
   >
   >     plt.annotate(code,
   >                xy=(.4, 0.1), ha='center', fontsize=fsize)
   >     plt.axis('off')
   >    
   > make_equation(mathext_demos)
   > ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can use variables in your string:

```
a = 5
b = 4
mathext_demos = (r'$(\frac{%s - \frac{1}{x}}{%s})$' %(str(a), str(b)))
```

You can also use `%f` for float, but I think that is something you have to figure out what works for you.

2. You can write a function with the arguments `a` and `b` for example en return the string. Is that what you meant with your second question?

```
def create_mathtext(a,b):
    c = a + b
    return r'${%s} = {%s} + {%s}$' % tuple(map(str, [c, a, b]))

make_equation( create_mathtext(1, 2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you 3DspatialUser, you got me what I needed! Edited code:

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt  

def make_equation(code,fsize=20,imgheight=70):
    fig=plt.figure(figsize=(7, 0.1))

    plt.annotate(code,
               xy=(.4, 0.1), ha='center', fontsize=fsize)
    plt.axis('off')
   

def create_mathtext(a="a",b="b",x="x"):
    c="c"
    if type(a)!=str:
        c = (a-1/x)/b
    return r'$%s=\frac{%s - \frac{1}{%s}}{%s}$' %(str(c), str(a),str(x), str(b)) 

make_equation( create_mathtext()) make_equation( create_mathtext(5,2.25,2))
```

Output:

[image]