# matplolib string: how to use a special character AND use a variable

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-3.8

I'm trying to put both a special character and a variable into a string in a matplotlib plot.  a lot of great info here {https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/text/mathtext.html} about special characters, but doesn't address using a variable in the string.

```
plt.plot(crossShoreC, -runningP, label=r'$\bar{P}_{%s}$'.format(win))
win='10' 
plt.text(0, 1, f"$\bar{P}")  # works

plt.text(4, 0.5, r"$\bar{P}$") # works -- from example in link

plt.text(1, 0, f"$\bar{P}_{win}")  # doesn't work 

plt.text(1, 0, r"$\bar{P}_{%s}".format(win))  #doesn't work 

plt.text(1, 0, r"$\bar{P}_{0}".format(win))  # doesn't work
```

this returns a `NameError: name 'x' is not defined` 
I'd like the output to be a latex like solution where `F_a=ma` # where `a` has two dots over it and the `_a` is a subscript

Comment: Here are the same questions as you and the [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69188835/python-matplotlib-mathtext-with-variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69188835/python-matplotlib-mathtext-with-variables).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: Thanks for clarifying your question, as suggested by @r-beginners, you can use expression `% (<variable 1>, <variable 2>, ...)` to format variable into string inside the format `r"$<special characters>$"`, so in this case, you can do something like below

```
plt.text(1, 0, r"$F_{%s}=m\ddot{a} \beta$" % (x))
```

Comment: please see the examples in the supplied link.  \ddot{a} is supposed to make an a with two dots above it